# Get guest names from Microsoft Teams attendance report using Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I would like to ask if anyone has managed to get the guest names (names that users input when they join from a browser) from the Microsoft Teams attendance report using the Microsoft Graph API. I know that you can get the names and ids from registered users, but I would like to know if there is a work-around to get guest names, too.

I'm asking this because in the report that is generated from the Teams app, guest names are displayed within the report with their respective attendance.

We have tried the same flow for registered users and it works as expected.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no way to retrieve guest names from the Microsoft Teams attendance report using the Graph API.

If you're interested, you can suggest this feature here:
[Microsoft Teams Community](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472)